# Tab missing on VC linked to Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I have a set of view controllers linked to a tab controller.
When a image is selected on one of these tabbed views a segue is executed and a detail viewocntroller not linked to the tab controlled is opened.

Pronblem is when I navigate back to the tabbed view controller via segue from the detail view, the tabs are no longer visible.

Before segue executed on tabbed vc:
[image]

Same vc with no tab after segue from vc not linked to tab controller
[image]

Question is how to ensure tab will be visible on vc when called via the non tabbed vc?

Just to add the tabbed view connected to tab controller is a collection view, the detail view segue is excited when user sects an image:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

println(segue.identifier)
        println(sender)


        println("SEGUE SELECTED:  \(segue.identifier)");

        if(segue.identifier == "segueToDetailScrollView"){

            // pass the cell 


            let cell = sender as CollectionViewCell;

            let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForCell(cell);

            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as ScrollView;

            var image = arrayOfIUmages[indexPath!.row];

            var imageTitle = titles[indexPath!.row];

            println("Image to segue name : \(image) and the title : \(imageTitle)");


            println("The vew controller \(vc)");

            vc.currImage = UIImage(named: arrayOfIUmages[indexPath!.row]);
            vc.textHeading = self.titles[indexPath!.row];


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a segue to the tabcontroller and let  tab controllers set the inner view. Onload you can check for a shared default or something similar to find which tab should be shown.

Comment: I had the same question as dancingbush but I'm a little confused by your answer. Can you expand on "let tab controllers set the inner view"? Is this done in a UITabBarController? How do you edit Onload?

Comment: Thanks John, also a bit lost as to how to check for a shared default to select which tab to be shown?

Comment: you can override the onload function then with a previously set execute defaults getStringForKey("keyname").

Defaults are a great way of storing state and it will persist between run instances.

Comment: Is there an onload func for viewcpntroller ? I no there is one for activity in android but wasn't aware for swift. getStringFirKey sounds like java?should that be defaults.stringForKey. Anyways not important still don't quite get the solution

Comment: Yep viewonload exists

Answer (score 0):

Need to use unwind method in target view controller to allow navigation back to the same instance navigated from, good example here http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2